# Anosov diffeomorfisms of S1

Tags: differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

I'm having problems trying to show that there are no Anosov diffeomorfisms on $S^1$, i.e. that $S^1$ is not an hyperbolic set for any diffeomorfism of $S^1$. Can someone help me?

I know I can assume that $\left\| d_x f^nv\right\| \le  c\lambda^n\left\| v\right\|$ ($\lambda <1$, $c>1$) for every $x\in S^1$ and $v\in\mathbb R$, but don't know how to follow from here...

Comment: The differential of Anosov diffeomorphism (correct me if I'm wrong) has to have both expanding and contracting directions at each point. This suggests that dimension of tangent space has to be at least two, and hence the dimension of a manifold must be at least two too.

Comment: @Evgeny Contraction or expansions are also Anosov diffeomorphisms. In general an Anosov diffeomorphism decomposes the tangent space in the contracting eigensubspace and the expanding eigensubspace; one of them can be zero dimensional.

Comment: @BalarkaSen Got it, although it doesn't look as an interesting case of Anosov diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a diffeomorphism $f : S^1 \to S^1$, you can choose a lift $F : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ to the universal cover $p : \Bbb R \to S^1$, $p(x) = \exp(2\pi i x)$. Since $f$ is a diffeomorphism of the circle, $F$ restricts to a diffeomorphism $g : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ such that for all $x \in [0, 1]$ and $n \in \Bbb Z$, $F(x + n) = g(x) + n$.

If $f$ is Anosov, then $df_p$ is either a contracting or an expanding linear transformation (the perks of having a single dimension) of $T_p S^1$ for all $p$. By compactness of the circle you can pick a global stretch factor, so let's assume that $df$ is globally $\lambda$-contracting for some $\lambda < 1$, i.e, $\|df_p(v)\| \leq \lambda \|v\|$ for all $p \in S^1$ and $v \in T_p S^1$.

Then $F'$ is also $\lambda$-contracting on $T_x \Bbb R$ for all $x$; in particular $g'$, where $F|_{[0, 1]} = g$, is also $\lambda$-contracting. But $g(0) = 0$ and $g(1) = 1$ implies by Lagrange's mean value theorem that for some $c \in (0, 1)$, $g'(c) = 1 > \lambda$, contradicting hypothesis.

Similar argument holds if you assume $df$ is globally $\lambda$-expanding for some $\lambda > 1$.